# python re match string with integer

Tags: python, regex, logging

I need to match strings like: `'2017-08-09,08:59:20.445 INFO {peers_peak_parameters_grid} [eval_peers_peak] Evaluating batch 0 out of 2158',`

I have tried different regular expressions such as: `comp = re.compile("Evaluating batch ^[-+]?[0-9]+$ out of ^[-+]?[0-9]+$")`

and this is an example usage:

```
def get_batch_process_time(log):                                                                                                                                                                            
    loglines = log.splitlines()                                                                                                                                                                             
    comp = re.compile("Evaluating batch ^[-+]?[0-9]+$ out of ^[-+]?[0-9]+$")                                                                                                                                
    times = []                                                                                                                                                                                              
    matches = []                                                                                                                                                                                            
    for i, line in enumerate(loglines):                                                                                                                                                                     
        if comp.search(line):                                                                                                                                                                               
            time = string2datetime(line.split(' ')[0])                                                                                                                                                      
            times.append(time)                                                                                                                                                                              
            matches.append(line)                                                                                                                                                                            
    return np.array(times), matches
```

Unfortunately none of the lines seems to match the given pattern. I assume that I'm using the wrong regular expression.

What is the right regular expression?
Am I using `re` correctly? (should I use match rather than search?)

Comment: Your string has no `out of`. [`Evaluating batch [-+]?[0-9]+ out of [-+]?[0-9]+`](https://regex101.com/r/B3hqgw/1) seems working if it does.

Comment: sorry there was an error in the question. I have edited the example string

Comment: use this pattern: `Evaluating batch [0-9]{4} out of [0-9]{4}`

Comment: @hadi which won't work if there's less than 1000 batches or more than 9999 ; it doesn't even work with the provided example since the first number is 0

Comment: I thought these numbers represent years, I apologize. use this: `Evaluating batch [0-9]+ out of [0-9]+`

Comment: @hadi no need to apologize, we all make mistakes ;) Thanks for being out there helping people out !

Comment: Thanks guys the important is that we solved ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`^[-+]?[0-9]+$` alone would match a whole string consisting of an optional plus or minus operation then a non-empty sequence of digits.

When I say a whole string, it's because `^` and `$` are "anchors" that will match respectively the start and end of the string, which is why your regex doesn't work.

I suppose you could also remove the optional sign part, i.e. `[-+]?`.

You could have found that out by yourself by testing your regex in [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/ukP7te/1) (check the explanation panel on the top right) or a similar utility.

Comment: so it is enough to remove `^` and `$`?

Comment: @Donbeo it should with the provided example, but I can't say for the rest of your data, which you haven't described.

Comment: I suppose he copied it from somewhere where `[-+]?` was necessary and the anchors were appropriate. Probably `\d+` would be enough here.

Comment: yes I have copied it. I only need to match 2 integers there as the logs is genereted using `%d`. I have never used re so I do not know what is the best practice. Your answer seems to work fine anyway

Comment: @Donbeo I would use `Evaluating batch \d+ out of \d+$` if the last number indeed is at the end of the line (otherwise remove the trailing `$`)